# Datepicker does not open after replacing HTML

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm trying to call function after changing div's content. problem is that datapicker stops to work. after changing content. Here is [**my demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/SD5Sh/7/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="value1">111
    <input type="text" class="datepickclass" style="width: 100px;" />
</div>
<div class="value2">2222
    <input type="text" class="datepickclass" style="width: 100px;" />
</div>
<div class="value3">333
    <input type="text" class="datepickclass" style="width: 100px;" />
</div>
<hr/>
<select class="dropdowndoc">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<div class="dropcontent"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.value1,.value2,.value3 {
    display:none;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.dropcontent').html($(".value1").html());

        $(".datepickclass").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            yearRange: '1930:2015', showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true
        });
        $('.FileUploadText').change(function () {
            $(this).closest('label').siblings('.path').val($(this).val());
        });
    $('.dropdowndoc').change(function () {
        // get the contents of the link that was clicked
        var linkText = $(this).val();
        if (linkText == 1) {
            var passForm = $(".value1").html();
        }
        if (linkText == 2) {
            var passForm = $(".value2").html();

        }
        if (linkText == 3) {
            var passForm = $(".value3").html();
        }


        $('.dropcontent').html(passForm);
        $(".datepickclass").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            yearRange: '1930:2015', showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: try unbinding the datepicker using $(".datepickclass").datepicker("destroy"); before you re-bind datepicker (I tried this in your fiddle, it's better but does not work without issues). However, honestly I would re-think the method you are using to achieve what you are doing. Even having your options already available in .dropcontent and then show/hide the relevant one might be better than bind/unbind/re-bind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When JavaScript executes `$(".datepickclass").datepicker({...});` this adds an `onclick` handler to all elements that have a class `datepickclass`. At this time there are 4 elements with that class, the original 3 + copied 1.

However, any of the `$(".valueX").html()` lines only duplicates the markup and **not** the events, so after adding the copied HTML, even though the `<input>` has the correct class, there is no `onclick` event, which is why the datepicker does not appear.

I thought it might be solvable with jQuery's [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method since that *can* duplicate event handlers. So I tried,

```
var passForm = $(".value1").clone(true, true);
```

but jQueryUI adds an `id` to the `<input>` when the datepicker is bound, so although the `onclick` handler gets copied the datepicker itself appears next to the (wrong) original `<input>` because the `id` was also duplicated.

You can get around this by following [How to clone jQuery Datepicker input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150968/how-to-clone-jquery-datepicker-input-field) but you might as well just stick with copying the HTML and call the `$(".datepickclass").datepicker({...});` again.

One slight catch is that jQueryUI will not reapply the datepicker if the element already has the class `hasDatepicker` so we need to remove that first.

```
$('.dropcontent').html(passForm);
$(".dropcontent .datepickclass").removeClass('hasDatepicker');
$(".dropcontent .datepickclass").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    yearRange: '1930:2015', showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true
});
```

Since there is now duplicated code, I would definitely refactor to remove the duplication and create a simpler solution.

For example see [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JHd7J/) or code below.

**JavaScript**

```
$(function () {
    cloneForm(1);
    initializeDatePickersFor('body');

    $('.FileUploadText').change(function () {
        $(this).closest('label').siblings('.path').val($(this).val());
    });

    $('.dropdowndoc').change(function() {
        cloneForm(this.selectedIndex + 1);
        initializeDatePickersFor('.dropcontent');
        return false;
    });

    function cloneForm(index) {
        var $input = $('.value' + index).html();
        $('.dropcontent').html($input);
    }

    function initializeDatePickersFor(selector) {
        var $inputs = $(selector).find('.datepickclass');
        $inputs.removeClass('hasDatepicker');

        $inputs.datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            yearRange: '1930:2015',
            showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your

```
$(".datepickclass").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            yearRange: '1930:2015', showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true
        });
```

to this:

```
$(document).on('focus', '.datepickclass:not(.hasDatepicker)',function(){
        $(this).datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            yearRange: '1930:2015', showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true})
    });
```

Comment: o tenx. it works. but how to call another function after .html? for example     $('.FileUploadText').on('change', function () {
        $(this).closest('label').siblings('.path').val($(this).val());
    });

Comment: I mean the main point of my change is that you want to attach the function with element dynamically. That is why I suggest you use .on(), but it doesn't mean you have to use it everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. '$(".datepickclass").datepicker({...})' is called when execution of the first line is done.

BTW, Fiddle works fine. Google Chrome 30.

```
$('.dropcontent').html(passForm)
$(".datepickclass").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    yearRange: '1930:2015', showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true
})
```

Comment: i'm calling datepicker twice. first on pageload, second after div content changed. before changing content it works. but after changing it doesn't. please look at http://jsfiddle.net/SD5Sh/7/

Comment: In your example datepicker "stops" because you remove it's trigger from DOM. jQuery selector string doesn't work like css. It just selects current elements in DOM that matches selector string. It doesn't watch DOM always. So, as you replace current element which has eventListener (on click)  that calls datepicker with new one which doesn't, you have to bind .datepicker() on your new element again.